# websockets with javascript and nginx on docker

Tags: javascript, docker, nginx, websocket, node-red

i have a docker compose that contains 3 containers " node-red , influxdb , a html with JavaScript webpage with nginx:alpine image "
in the html and JavaScript webpage i have a list of images and i change the image according to the data that come from node red via websockets

[image]

and i receive my data with this JavaScript function

```html
function startConnect() {
    document.getElementById('dt').click();
    socket = new WebSocket("ws://mywebsite.com:1880/ws/test");
    socket.onmessage = function(e) {onMessageArrived(e.data)}
    console.log("connected");
    socket.onopen = function() {socket.send("1")};
    
}

// Called when a message arrives
function onMessageArrived(message) {
    console.log("onMessageArrived: " + message);
    
    var obj = JSON.parse(message);
    
    document.getElementById("image1").src = "myimage/" + obj.L + "_DL.png";
    document.getElementById("image2").src = "myimage/" + obj.M + obj.F + obj.S + "_" + obj.Z48_70 + "_M.png";
    document.getElementById("image3").src = "myimage"+ obj.V + obj.V + "_X";
}
```

every thing worked fine until i have decided to use docker for "node-red and influx and the html webpage" and use nginxwithout docker with letsencrypt certifacts to handle the reverse proxy of my 3 containers.

The problem that i am facing is that i cannot receive data with websockets even though i change the `socket = new WebSocket("ws://mywebsite.com:1880/ws/test")` to `socket = new WebSocket("ws://mywebsite.com:6100/ws/test")` the port 6100 used by my webpage  contain with this i am having an https error and with `socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.170.0.6:6100/ws/test")` the IP address of my webpage container and also with `new WebSocket("ws://mywebsite/webpage/ws/test")` this is handeled by nginx to route it the IP and the port used by my webpage container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connecting to a WebSocket address that is being boot strapped via HTTPS then you need to use the `wss:` scheme rather than `ws:`

So if you have enabled https on port 6100 then you need to use `wss://mywebsite.com:6100/ws/test`

(also if you are using nginx as a reverse proxy is there any reason not to use the default ports of 80 and 443 for http/https respectively?)

EDIT:
If your proxy is presenting the default ports of 80/443 for http/https respectively then you should be using something like the following:

```
function startConnect() {
    document.getElementById('dt').click();
    if (location.scheme === 'http:' ) {
      socket = new WebSocket("ws://mywebsite.com/ws/test");
    } else {
      socket = new WebSocket("wss://mywebsite.com/ws/test");
    }
    socket.onmessage = function(e) {onMessageArrived(e.data)}
    console.log("connected");
    socket.onopen = function() {socket.send("1")};
    
}
```

This will pick `ws://` or `wss://` depending on how the page is loaded (http vs https)

Comment: i tried to use wss but i get https error failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Comment: for the nginx any http/https come from outside the server is using  port 443 and nginx handle the reverse proxy

Comment: Then you should remove the port number in the `wss://` URL